# MS ACCESS application get crashing after applying filter to certain queries

Tags: ms-access-2010

Currently I am developing an Access 2013 based Application for tracking evaluation information of the school students. The database contains only 3 simple tables:

1. tblSubjects = Contains different subject information
2. tblStudents = Contains student's personal information
3. tblMarks = Contains subject wise evaluation marks for each student

and few other queries based on these 3 tables. Now I have a (bit ugly) sql query like following:

```
SELECT tblStudents.*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qryPapers WHERE qryPapers.STUDID=tblStudents.STUDID) AS PAPER_COUNT, 
(SELECT SUM(MR_TOTAL) FROM qryPapers WHERE qryPapers.STUDID=tblStudents.STUDID) AS ALL_TOTAL, 
(SELECT MIN(MR_TOTAL) FROM qryPapers WHERE qryPapers.STUDID=tblStudents.STUDID AND qryPapers.PAPER_TYPE LIKE 'E?') AS MIN_ELEC, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qryPapers WHERE qryPapers.STUDID=tblStudents.STUDID AND qryPapers.PAPER_TYPE LIKE 'A?') AS LANG_PS,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qryPapers WHERE qryPapers.STUDID=tblStudents.STUDID AND qryPapers.PAPER_TYPE LIKE 'E?') AS ELCT_PS,
IIf([PAPER_COUNT]>5,ALL_TOTAL-MIN_ELEC,ALL_TOTAL) AS [GT],
IIf([LANG_PS]=2 And [ELCT_PS]>=3,'PASS','FAIL') AS STATUS
FROM tblStudents;
```

The Problem is, whenever I try to run a **filter on the STATUS field** of this query (Like When STATUS='PASS') the entire ACCESS is first **STOPES RESPONDING**! and then **SHUTS DOWN and RESTARTS**.

I have no idea what is going on here. I have seen far more complex queries running perfectly well, but not this one. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this a lot in Access. I don't know the cause of the problem but I just export the query to Excel or create a table based on the query to apply filtering.

Comment: In my case I can not just export it to any excel or a table. My question is why this is happening. As I mentioned I have seen much more complex query with a truck load of subqueries is running perfectly well.

Comment: @Tamonash Gupta. Try to compact and repair the database and execute the query again.